# Jquery Datepicker : Never show the day selection "ui-datepicker-calendar"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need a datepicker to never show the day section.

I want to thus destroy/remove this element : "ui-datepicker-calendar"

It must never show. I want to only use the date and year selection.

The best place it seems is to look at "beforeShow"

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', beforeShow: myFunction});

function myFunction(input,inst)
{
    alert(inst);
    $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").remove();
   //$(".ui-datepicker-calendar").destroy(); //this causes infinite loop
}
```

It this possible?
http://jsfiddle.net/UEnqL/9/

I have tried "destroy", "hide" it just comes back on the next click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#datepicker").focus(function(){
    $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").remove()
})
```

Use the above code to remove the "ui-datepicker-calendar" section.